# How to hide answers (some of the answer in the next questions - multiple choice) in google form based on the answer in the previous questions

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a google form to conduct a survey. Based on the answer updated on Question 3, i want to hide some of the answer in Question 4  as I don't want participants to select those answer. Is there a way for me to do it on Google Form. A friend of mine suggested to create sections but i don't want to create multiple sections as the questions are the same but the choice of answers are limited based on the previous question's answer.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple sections is the only way to do that when using plain vanilla Google Sheets. To get variations of a question, you will have to create copies of the question, and put each variant in a section of its own.

Note that each variant of the question will have its own column in the form responses sheet, so you may have to **Insert > Sheet** in the response destination spreadsheet and use array formulas there to aggregate the results into a smaller number of columns.